# Posts in Page - How to customize the URL?

Tags: posts, permalinks, pages, url-rewriting

I have a "normal" WordPress install.
Blogposts are displayed on the homepage an there are a few pages.

Now I want to display the posts of a specific category on a page, so that I can add some additional info above the post list.

First, I created the page in the WP Admin (ex. "Awesome Posts", page ID: 31)

Then I created a new page template, named it after the page id (page-31.php) and in there I created another WP_Query to get the posts of some category.

```
<?php
  // The default "page" content
  while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    get_template_part( 'content', 'single' );
  endwhile;

  // Custom category query
  $awesome= new WP_Query( 'category_name=awesome' );
  if ( $awesome->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $awesome->have_posts() ) : $awesome->the_post();
      get_template_part( 'content', 'awesome' );
    endwhile;
  endif;
?>
```

This works as expected and I get a list of awesome posts on my page.
The URL of this page is `/awesome`. 
My permalink structure is `/%postname%/` so that normal posts on the homepage get a URL like `/postname`.
Now I would like to have the posts on this specific page link to `/awesome/posttitle` and this is where I get stuck.

Do you now of a way to achive this?

Comment: I do not think that will be straight-way possible. What you are trying to do is more like a category page. Why not create a category called "awesome" and have [category specific page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates) for this? On the top of the posts listing you can query for the content of a specific page as you want to display. In this way you can maintain the urls as you have referred.

Comment: You are right. For the case I mentioned the category page would be the easiest solution. I was thinking about "WordPress as a CMS" where you have mostly pages and on some of these pages you could have different news sections. Or maybe some custom post types.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can see this working is by setting a couple of redirect rules in your .htaccess file. You'd have to manually redirect all your posts (that you want with that permalink structure) and prepend the /awesome URL part in front.

Other than the aforementioned solution, which is a hack more than anything, I'm afraid that what you're looking for is not possible. As @Florian Grell said above, this is a behaviour best suited for categories rather than pages.